# How can I run Rails on Maglev?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, maglev

How can I run Rails on Maglev? It seems that it can run Sinatra, but not full blown Rails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An update.  MagLev can now run some basic rails 3.0 apps.  look at examples/rails in the MagLev distribution https://github.com/MagLev/maglev/tree/master/examples/rails

Answer (score 2):

MagLev does not yet run rails, but it is on our radar...

Comment: Thanks Peter, I'll keep a lookout