# Can Jekyll run on MagLev?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, maglev

[MagLev](http://maglev.github.io/) tries to be compatible with ruby 1.8.7

So it seems to me that [Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) should be able to run on it...

And based on this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2276556/how-can-i-run-rails-on-maglev), seems that even some rails applications can run on it...

- But has anyone actually tried it?
- What were the problems you had?
- If you haven't tried it, do you anticipate any major problems?

TIA

Comment: Why the downvotes it is a legitimate question.
Can Jekyll run on Maglev? 
is a programming question, 
can be objectively answered

Comment: No idea why it is getting downvoted. Out of curiosity, why would you use MagLev for this?

Comment: I've read reports that Jekyll starts to be really slow at generating the site at around 500 posts. This is because it regenerates the whole blog everytime you recreate it. 

And I have a community site with around 6,000 articles.

There is a feature planned so that it doesn't regenerate everytime... but not untill jekyll 1.5 or more...

So I want to take advantage of MagLev's speed to buy me sometime until jekyll 1.5.

Comment: There are other ways you could try and optimise Jekyll such as choosing a faster markdown engine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried Jekyll on Maglev's 1.9 branch, and it doesn't work. Maglev falls down when using anything with C extensions; in this case, it's Jekyll's dependency on posix-spawn.

You might wanna check out the docs regarding [the state of C extensions on Maglev](https://github.com/MagLev/maglev/blob/master/docs/Maglev_c_extensions.md).

AFAIK, Jekyll doesn't really have persistence (besides static files), so I'm not sure what you'd gain from using Maglev. You can definitely have a lot of fun with Maglev and Sinatra, give them a shot.